# Need help with Integral for a Normal Distribution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

The question is asking me to find the integral,
$$\int_{-1}^1 x \exp(-(x^2+x^4)) \, dx.$$
-No calculator and approximate value
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's the integral of an _odd_ function over an interval that is symmetric about $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 9):

**hint**: The function is continuous and *odd* with the interval being $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Well. that's bit is a bit obvious. I should have clarified that I'm looking for an approx. value without a calculator (so it doesn't throw and erf on me http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)

Answer (score 3):

For the definite integral over an interval that is symmetric about $0$, you already received the answer.

If you had to compute the antiderivative, it is rather simple : start completing the square
$$x^2+x^4=\left(x^2+\frac 12 \right)^2-\frac 14$$ making $$I=\int x\, e^{-(x^2+x^4)}\,dx=e^{\frac 14}\int \, x \,e^{-\left(x^2+\frac 12 \right)^2}\,dx=\frac 12 {e^{\frac 14}}\int  \,e^{-\left(x^2+\frac 12 \right)^2}\,d(x^2+\frac 12)$$ and the change of variable $x^2+\frac 12=y$ will make 
$$I=\frac 12 {e^{\frac 14}}\int e^{-y^2}\,dy=\frac 14 {e^{\frac 14}}\sqrt \pi \,\text{erf}(y)=\frac 14 {e^{\frac 14}}\sqrt \pi \,\text{erf}\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$